# Laravel Query builder - ->offset() doesnt want to work with computed column

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I'm using query builder and have this query which works

```
$athletes = DB::table('athletes')
            ->select("athletes.first_name", "athletes.last_name",
                DB::raw('MAX(performance) AS personal_best')
            )
            ->leftJoin("performances", "athletes.id", "=", "performances.athlete_id")
            ->groupBy("athletes.id", "athletes.first_name", "athletes.last_name")
            ->orderBy("personal_best", "DESC")
            ->get();
```

but now I need to do pagination so I added

```
->offset(5)
->limit(10)
```

and now it is giving me an error:

> Invalid column name 'personal_best'

I was trying to find a solution to this but so far with no success. If anybody has any idea it would be very welcomed!

Comment: You can debug your query using `->toSql()` instead of `->get()`. The most clear solution here would be to `->orderBy(DB::raw('MAX(performance)'), "DESC")`

Comment: It gives me the query and if i run the raw query it gives me the same mistake. Which is what I dont know how to fix

Comment: Yes this works... would you know what is it?

Comment: Just read bot raw queries. you will have you're answer